# Can I avoid templating a class which needs to have a templated member?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes: `CFileFinderThread` encapsulates a worker thread and `CFileFinderCallbackForwarder` forwards thread data to one of several possible external callback functions (with different signatures). The type of callback function is a template parameter for the forwarder.

```
CFileFinderCallbackForwarder<zCallBack> forwarder(zcallback);
CFileFinderThread<zCallBack> thread(forwarder);
while (thread.WaitForThread(0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    bool eventSignaled = ::WaitForSingleObject(forwarder.getCallbackSignal(), 
                                               DEFAULT_CALLBACK_MILLIS)
                         == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
    forwarder.ExternalCallback(eventSignaled);
}
```

The thread class keeps a reference to an instance of the forwarder, and calls methods in the forwarder to store data in it – but only methods which do not use the template parameter in any way. The only method which is actually different depending on the template parameter is `ExternalCallback`.

**Is it possible to avoid templating the thread class with the type of the callback function that is used by the forwarder?**

Or what would be an alternative? Because the thread really shouldn't care at all about what the forwarder will do with its data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could use [type erasure](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Type_Erasure) for this.

Comment: If you mean "member variable", no you can't. If you mean "member function", yes you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide your forwarder class into a **non-generic base class and a generic derived class**. The non-generic base class should, obviously, contain all non-generic data and operations; the derived class should contain the `ExecuteCallback` function.

This allows you to make the thread class non-generic as well.

Here is a simplified yet full example:

```
// non-generic base:
class CFileFinderCallbackForwarderBase
{
private:
    int i;
protected:
    // making the constructor protected here is just good practice:
    CFileFinderCallbackForwarderBase() {}
public:
    void SetData() { i = 0; }
};

// thread class is now non-generic
class CFileFinderThread
{
private:
    // thread class is non-generic because it only uses
    // the base class:
    CFileFinderCallbackForwarderBase* forwarder;

public: 
    CFileFinderThread(CFileFinderCallbackForwarderBase* forwarder) :
        forwarder(forwarder)
    {
    }

    void f()
    {
        forwarder->SetData();
    }
};

// derived class is generic:
template <class T>
class CFileFinderCallbackForwarder : public  CFileFinderCallbackForwarderBase
{
public:
    void ExternalCallback()
    {
        T t;
        t = 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CFileFinderCallbackForwarder<int> forwarder;
    CFileFinderThread thread(&forwarder);
    forwarder.ExternalCallback();
}
```

A positive side effect of this technique may be reduced code bloat.

Comment: @Puppy: That's why I said "may be". And it's just a side effect anyway. OTOH, perhaps the OP currently has hundreds of instantiations... :)

Comment: Did you really just downvote the answer because of the statement at the end? It may be a questionable one despite all weasel words, but I wonder if something is wrong with the technique itself.

Comment: I did, and it was because of the terrible idiotic code bloat comment.

Comment: @Puppy: Let's leave the code bloat line aside for a moment, despite the surprisingly insulting tone of your comment. But what exactly is terrible about the solution in general, in the context of the OP's situation?

Comment: All you appear to have done is reimplemented std::function but poorly.

Comment: @Puppy: That does not sound very convincing to me. It is a simplified example, after all, which precisely answers the question asked (and which has the extra advantage of working with pure C++03). Of course, the OP could just rewrite the entire class. But this is not always feasible. I hope you don't object to details which would be important in production code but meaningless in the context of the big picture here; e.g. error checking or the use of a raw pointer with unclear ownership semantics.